# find files more than 100 MB from ls -1hl command's output

Tags: python, linux

I'm doing `ls -1lh` command on certain directories and displaying the output on the GUI.

description of options used in ls command

```
1 --> print one file/directory in one line
l --> long listing
h --> human readable format (converting in KB, MB, G)
```

now i have sizes extracted from `ls -1lh` command:-

```
size = ["100","9.6K","12M","79M","679M","222K","23","132M","3G","1.3G"]
```

now i want to find out what sizes are more than 100M in python

What could be my approach? i have to use `ls -1lh` command because user wants to see the long listing on the directoires

Comment: You really should not be [parsing `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Traversing the file system and doing `stat()` on the files and producing `ls`-like output from that is much more straightforward than the opposite.

Comment: What about the '-S' option - it will sort your output by file size. You'll only have to look at the bottom part of the list.

Comment: Why don't you use `find`? `find -maxdepth 1 -size +100M`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
units = dict(K=1024, M=1024*1024, G=1024*1024*1024)
def parse_size(s):
    times = units.get(s[-1:], 1)
    if times == 1:
        return float(s)
    else:
        return float(s[:-1]) * times
```

Usage:

```
>>> size = ["100","9.6K","12M","79M","679M","222K","23","132M","3G","1.3G"]
>>> threshold = parse_size('100M')
>>> print [s for s in size if parse_size(s) >= threshold]
['679M', '132M', '3G', '1.3G']
```

BTW, how about using `find` if you want to get list of files that is larger than 100MB? `find -maxdepth 1 -size +100M`